# I wrote function for betadisper anova for all column values using a for loop but is giving me the error of non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

```
betad_func <- function(physeqobj){ 

  sd = data.frame(sample_data(physeqobj)) #sample_data data frame (mapping file/ meta data)

  tOTU <- t(phyloseq::otu_table(physeqobj)) #combining the OTU table and sample data (data)

  table_vegan <- cbind(sd,tOTU) 

  dis < vegdist(tOTU) #the distance matrix
  
  results <- list()
for(i in colnames(sd)){

    groups <- factor(sd$i)
    mod <- betadisper(dis,groups)
    temp <- list(anova(mod))
    results[[i]] <- temp
    
  }
  return(results)
}
betad_func(physeq1)
```

Comment: hey! Please add a bit more details to your question: 1) the dataset we can use to test your function 2) description of an error and expected outcome of your function

Comment: I want the function to take a phyloseq object(phyloseqobj) and do the analysis. 
To create the sample data I used the code in this tutorial https://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/import-data.html 

my expected output is a betadisper function which shows me the anova analysis for all the columns in my sample data. 

but I am getting an error of  "non confirmational array"

Comment: column_names <- colnames(sd)
for(i in column_names){
groups <- factor(sd$i)
# mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)
# mod
# anova(mod)
}

with this code I want the output to be the factors in the column of a dataframe "sd" but I am getting the error as 
Error in x - c : non-conformable arrays
I am fairly new to r, so I don't know how debug this error

Comment: have you tried it line by line to see which line does not work?